# Web app development - How to transfer text in real time from one logged-in session to another?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous, real-time

I'm developing a web app with vanilla Javascript/PHP, which is mostly supposed to be used on desktop. The user can create and edit notes, and I added an option to make it possible to dictate your notes from microphone input using `webkitSpeechRecognition`.

I'd like to enable the user to use their mobile device's microphone in case they don't have one for the PC. They'd do it by logging in the app from the phone; if the app detects an open note editing session on PC, it offers the user a button to record, recognize and send over the text to the PC session in real time.

Recognizing the open editing session from the mobile app and enabling speech recognition is rather straightforward. What I'm struggling about is finding an efficient way of sending over the text in real time. I thought about having a database entry for the text, which the phone feeds to and the PC session reads from constantly (by sending tons of `XMLHttpRequest`s), but that seems too cumbersome of an approach.

Is there any other more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This kind of communication is best suited to using websockets to communicate with a shared server process, similar to the way online games work.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply, can you link me to some resources on how to do that? I never worked with protocols outside HTTP.

Comment: Google "websockets tutorial"

Comment: HTTP is TCP; over TLS if secured. Web Sockets is the same thing essentially but a step faster than HTTP you initiate once and stay connected. If you would like to go a step faster, use the WebRTC DataChannels, a simple SFU like media-soup can get you going fast and can scale. Which is referred to Real-Time protocol (RTP or SRTP). For simplicity you should achieve this with web-sockets. It'd be as easy as ws.send(JSON.stringify({'text':'I was just converted now, server will see this shortly.'});

Comment: https://pusher.com/ is not free, but it's quite easy to set up and use. Highly recommend if you're looking for a simple way to do realtime communication like this.